# Why spend long time,when .net SqlClient executes BeginTransaction

Tags: asp.net-core, sqlclient

I have multiple services on their respective machines,that are virtual machines on different host.

When I call SqlClient method BeginTransaction(), occasionally it takes 6 seconds or 12 seconds to complete.

```
_stopwatch.Start();

conn.BeginTransaction();

_stopwatch.Stop();

var milliSec = _stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

_logger.LogInformation($"BeginTransaction() spend {milliSec} milliSec.");
```

Connection string:

```
Data source=192.168.1.1;initial catalog=db;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=my;
```

Log:

```
08:14:05.000,host:A,BeginTransaction() spend 12894.685 milliSec.
08:14:05.000,host:A,BeginTransaction() spend 12959.3291 milliSec.
08:14:03.000,host:B,BeginTransaction() spend 12964.8313 milliSec.
08:14:03.000,host:C,BeginTransaction() spend 13021.6212 milliSec.
08:14:01.000,host:B,BeginTransaction() spend 6547.2403 milliSec.
08:13:07.000,host:A,BeginTransaction() spend 13016.0886 milliSec.
08:13:07.000,host:D,BeginTransaction() spend 12897.8952 milliSec.
08:13:04.000,host:C,BeginTransaction() spend 6442.9338 milliSec.
```

```
Framewrok : .net core 2.2
SqlClient version : 4.6.0
```

This happened is not the peak of the request nor the peak of the Database.

In one minute(08:13:04~08:14:10),our services handle about 400 requests.

Mostly BeginTransaction() completed immediately.

What is the cause?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried attaching a profiler? (e.g dotprofile from jetbrains).

Comment: Thanks for your advice.I will try it.